# function searching in an array of structures - stop condition unknown

Tags: c, pointers, struct

The following program stores every word and then prints them with a number of occurrences.
Global `typedef` declaration:

```
typedef struct {
    char * word;
    int occ;
}
words;
words *data=NULL;
```

I have a problem with the search function. I've created a function returning `int` that looks like this: (`max` is the constantly updated size of an array of structures, that's why I call search function after `EOF` is reached.)

```
int search(char *word,int max)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<max; i++)
    {
        if(!strcmp(data[i].word,word)) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

But I noticed I'm supposed to write a search function having that prototype:

```
struct abc *find(char *word)
```

So I've created the following code:

```
struct words *findword(char *word)
{
    struct words *ptr;

    for (ptr = data; ptr != NULL; ptr++) {      /* IS THE STOP CONDITION OK? */
        if (strcmp(word, ptr->word) == 0)
            return ptr;
    }
    return NULL;          

}
```

And I receive many errors during compilation:

> reverse.c: In function ‘findword’:
>
> reverse.c:73: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
>
> reverse.c:73: error: increment of pointer to unknown structure
>
> reverse.c:73: error: arithmetic on pointer to an incomplete type
>
> reverse.c:74: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
>
> reverse.c: In function ‘main’:
>
> reverse.c:171: error: ‘which’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>
> reverse.c:171: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
>
> reverse.c:171: error: for each function it appears in.)
>
> make: *** [reverse.o] Error 1

---

`which` is an `int` variable assigned to the return of my firstly written search function.
The error with `which` is easily fixed, but I don't know how to replace that (solution working with my base search function):

`data[which].occ++;`

How to fix it so that it'll work with my new approach to search?

---

**EDIT**

`main()` added:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *word;
    words *temp;
    int c,i,num;
    /*int which;*/
    FILE *infile;

    if(argc!=2) {}      
    if((infile=fopen(argv[1],"r"))==NULL) {}
    num=0;
    while(1)
    {
        c=fgetc(infile);
        if(c==EOF) break;
        if(!isalpha(c)) continue;
        else ungetc(c,infile);
        word=getword(infile);
        word=convert(word);
        /*which=search(word,num);*/ 
        if(findword(word))
        {
            if(!(temp=realloc(data,sizeof(words)*(num+1))))
            {}
            else
                data=temp;
            data[num].word=strdup(word);
            data[num].occ=1;
            num++;
        }
        else
            data[which].occ++;

        free(word);
    }
    sort(num-1);
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {}
    free(data);
    if(fclose(infile))
    {}  
    return 0;
}
```

I've left `{}` for the irrelevant pieces of code eg. error handling.

---

**EDIT2**
The things I'm asking for above, are fixed. However, I get a seg fault now.
I'll give a link to the whole code, I don't want to put it in an edited post since it'd create a big mess. Seg fault is caused by lines 73 and 152 (strcmp is not working somehow). Hope that full code will be easier to understand.
[FULL CODE](http://pastebin.com/t3t7Cr5D)

Comment: Why not just move that `int max` parameter to a global variable and use the first version of the code? The second version is going to crash because the pointer is going to be incremented and incremented beyond the end of the `data[]` array.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze I can't use the first function since it returns `int` and I should return particular place in an array of structures. Ad.2 - How to fix that, so that the pointer stops incrementing at the end of constantly expanding array of structures?

Comment: Return `&data[i]` instead of `i`, what's the problem with that? You can't fix that pointer other than by 1) introducing an element counter (or a pointer to the last element) and comparing the currently examined location with that OR, which I don't recommend, 2) embedding a special indicator in the last element of data[] and checking it.

Comment: Could you add the code from your `main()` function please?

Comment: So only `main` knows how big your array of `words` is. You need to either store that gobally alongside `data`, or store a magic value to mark the end: then, you can write a loop that stops without overrunning the array, and without passing the size into your `findword` function.

Comment: /* IS THE STOP CONDITION OK? */ No, see below.

Comment: @Scooter Yes, I've seen Your reply, but I've changed my code according to Mike's advice. There's no `for` loop now in my `findword` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems are with your findword function, lets go through all the lines

```
struct words *ptr;
```

This is not what you ment to do. The `typedef` you used in defining the structure allows you to not need to write `struct` anymore. This is why you're getting the error: `reverse.c:73: error: increment of pointer to unknown structure`. What you want is just:

```
words *ptr;
```

Next, the loop:

```
for(ptr=data; //This is fine, you're assigning your local ptr to the global data. I assume that's something valid

ptr != NULL; //That could OK too... we can loop while ptr is not NULL
ptr++)       //This line makes no sense...
```

You may want to look up how for loops work again, the point is you're incrementing something until it hits a condition. ptr++ will move where you're pointing too, so you'll no longer be pointing to your structure.

I need to see your `main()` function to understand what you're trying to accomplish, but based on the prototype you have to follow, I think the easiest solution would be something like:

```
void main()
{
    // init your vars
    bool more_words_to_add = true;
    words *ptr = NULL;
    int i;

    // populate your array of words
    while(more_words_to_add) {
        for(i = 0; i<max; i++) {
          if(ptr = findword("word"))  //if we find the word
            ptr->occ++;  //increment the number of times we found it
          else {
            //I don't know what you want to do here, it's not clear what your goal is.
            //Add the new word to your array of words and set occ to 1,
            //then increment max because there's one more word in your array?
          }
        }
        //get the next word to fine, or else set more_words_to_add = false to break
    }
}
```

If this type of solution is what you're looking to do, then you can adjust your findwords function to be very simple:

```
struct words *findword(char *word)
{
    words *ptr = data;
    if (strcmp(word, ptr->word) == 0)
        return ptr;
    return NULL;
}
```

**EDIT:** For your new error I suspect the problem is with your memory allocation, see this short example of using your structure:

```
words *findword(char *word)
{
    words *ptr = data;
    if(strcmp(word, ptr->word) == 0)
      return ptr;
    return NULL;
}

int main(){
    words *ptr;

    data = realloc(data, sizeof(words));
    data->word = "hello";                //DO NOT SKIP THESE LINES
    data->occ = 0;                       //DO NOT SKIP THESE LINES

    if(ptr = findword("hello")) {
      ptr->occ++;
      printf("I found %d %s's\n",ptr->occ, ptr->word);
    }
} 

mike@linux-4puc:~> ./a.out 
I found 1 hello's
```

You can see here that you need to alloc some memory for the global structure then you can store data in it and pass pointers to it.

**EDIT 2:**

Your `main()` code does this:

```
if((ptr = findword(word)))
{
     //do stuff
}
else
  ptr->occ++;
```

That's not going to work because if findword() fails it returns NULL, so in the if check ptr is set to NULL, then in the else you're trying to deference NULL. If (and keep in mind I'm not really reading your logic so this is up to you) you really want to increment ptr->occ if a word is not found then you want this instead:

```
if(findword(word))
{
     ptr = findword(word);
     //do stuff
}
else
  ptr->occ++; //increments the current ptr's occ, no new ptr was assigned.
```

Comment: Thank You. I've removed all the errors (following Your post) from compiling stage. However, now I'm getting Segmentation fault and valgrind indicates two lines causing error: `if (strcmp(word, ptr->word) == 0)` and `if(findword(word))` from `main` Any advice what is wrong with these?

Comment: Your code is getting a little hard to think about. Can you clean it up to the current version since you're done to these new problems? I suspect the problem is with your memory allocation, see my EDIT on my post as to how to use that global structure and see if that helps.

Comment: I'll give a link to the whole code, I don't want to put it in an edited post since it'd create a big mess. Seg fault is caused by lines 73 and 152 (strcmp is not working). Hope that full code will be easier to understand. [link](http://pastebin.com/t3t7Cr5D)

Comment: The problem is you didn't follow my example. :) I re-edited it, see the `//DO NOT SKIP THESE LINES` part? What you're doing in your code is allocating memory but not initializing it to anything. That makes data->word a bad pointer. Now in my code I made it "hello" but you can just make it an empty string "" or just do a memset of 0 or whaever you want, but you NEED to initialize before you use.

Comment: Thank You. Now it almost works - got oe new error on the marked line [link] (http://pastebin.com/SWrrMgFc) Should I repeat `realloc` for `ptr` as well?

Comment: Yes, you would be getting an error there. The if check is: `if((ptr = findword(word)))` What does that mean? That means if you got a valid return from findword. Else you're returning NULL from that function. Now in your else you're trying `ptr->occ++`. That means you're deferencing a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (ptr = data; ptr != NULL; ptr++) {    
/* IS THE STOP CONDITION OK? */
```

No. Your pointer just keeps getting incremented. The only thing that would make it NULL in that code is integer overflow. You could look at what it points to, and see if that is NULL, IF you preset the data area to 0's:

```
#define NUM_WORDS 100
data = calloc(NUM_WORDS,sizeof(words));
```

Or

```
#define NUM_WORDS 100
int bytes = NUM_WORDS * sizeof(words);
data = malloc(bytes);
memset(data,0,bytes);
```

....

```
for (ptr = data; ptr->word != NULL; ptr++) {
```

If you don't want to preset the data area to 0 then you will have to pass the current amount of structs currently held in the data area to your function in order to know how much to loop.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as `struct words` in your program; there's an unnamed `struct` type, and a typedef `words` to that type.  Either use `struct words` or `words` consistently.

You'll then need to replace

```
data[which].occ++;
```

with

```
result->occ++;
```

where `result` is the return value from your new search function.

Comment: I'm using `words` as You can see. I suppose it is wrong name then, what should I change to omit those compiler errors?

Comment: @PeterKowalski no, you're using `struct words`.